# What was "m(o)ustache" called before the term entered the English language?

Tags: word-usage, archaicisms

"[Mustache](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mustache)"  appears to be from the mid-late 16th century of  French, possibly Italian/Spanish origin.

> - 1580s, from French moustache (15c.), from Italian mostaccio, from Medieval Greek moustakion.
> - Borrowed earlier (1550s) as mostacchi, from the Italian word or its Spanish derivative mostacho. The plural form of this, mustachios, lingers in English.
>   (Etymonline)

One can reasonably assume that mustaches were commonly worn also before the 16th century as the following [source](https://www.timetoast.com/timelines/mustaches-and-beards-1500-2013) shows:

[image]

***Jan. 1st, 1535  - Henry  VIII***

"*In Enland Henry VIII brought back the beard and mustache look. Men wore whatever length and style that suited them*".

Questions:

What was the common Middle English term for mustache and why was it replaced? Was mustache used in some literary work that made it popular for instance?

Comment: In fact mustaches were rare in western Europe in the middle ages and renaissance down to the 15th century; the only portrait from the period I can think of which depicts a mustache unaccompanied by a beard is that of Vlad the Impaler, who reigned beyond the pale of Catholic Christianity.

Comment: In the Bayeux Tapestry, King Harold and his knights are shown with moustaches while the Normans are clean-shaven.

Comment: The Old English Translator (http://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk) gives "granu", but I have never seen anything like that, nor the Dutch "snor", Norse "bart" or German "Schnurrbart" used in English...

Comment: they probably referred to it as a catapillar.

Answer (score 39):

The most likely answer to the first question is that one would simply refer to the facial hair above the upper lip as a kind of **beard**.

An early attestation in *OED* under "mustachio" from **1551** -- in fact, the earliest attestation of either "mustachio," "mustache," or any variants, explicitly denotes the word this way.

> **1551** They suffer their **mostacchi** to growe a quarter of a yarde longer than their beardes. [margin] **Mostacchi is the berde of the vpper lyppe**.

- William Thomas · *G. Barbaro's Trav. Persia*

"Beard" is attested as early as *circa* 825, making it a much earlier term than "mustache."

Using the word "beard" to refer to a mustache didn't disappear either. This citation from 1760 poses an example of such a use, even though the word mustache would have been well-established by the time of its writing.

> **1760**: [The Britons] shaved the **beard** on the chin; **that on the upper lip** was suffered to remain.

- Edmund Burke · *An essay towards an abridgment of the English history* · 1760.

---

As to why the word "mustache" made its rise in the 16th century, I can only speculate.  I have no reason to believe the word grew out of any particularly notable use, like that of Shakespeare in **1598**.

> It will please his Grace..sometime to..dallie with my excrement, with my **mustachie**

- ["Love's Labor Lost" from *The Complete Works of William Shakespeare*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xVSWAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT2993&dq=It%20will%20please%20his%20Grace..sometime%20to..dallie%20with%20my%20excrement,%20with%20my%20mustache&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwlfabiezVAhVoyoMKHYNtCaAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=It%20will%20please%20his%20Grace..sometime%20to..dallie%20with%20my%20excrement%2C%20with%20my%20mustache&f=false)

It would be another notch on a very long belt.

Answer (score 17):

The Middle English Dictionary, in its entry for [hēr (n.)](http://quod.lib.umich.edu.ezaccess.libraries.psu.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED20433&egs=all&egdisplay=open) ("hair") lists "hereliste" as a compound meaning mustache, as used in this quote:

> Iowe, temples, et iernoun -- Cheke, thonewonges, and **hereliste**.

(The quote is from *Nominale siue Verbale in Gallicis cum expositione eiusdem in Anglicis* (1350) which I think translates to "Nominal or verbal in French with an exposition of the same in English". Full thing can be read in this [paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-968X.1906.tb00148.x/abstract), which is unfortunately paywalled.)

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any other instances of this word (due to its absence in OED, how many different ways it could be spelled, false positives while searching, etc).

Comment: The text of Skeat's paper on *Nominale sive Verbale* is available in a rather poorly-OCR'd version on [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/transactionsphi17britgoog/transactionsphi17britgoog_djvu.txt). I rather think the OCR errors make this transcription less than helpful as a source for Middle English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: If you click "see other formats", you can view a scanned version: https://archive.org/details/transactionsphi17britgoog

Answer (score 15):

In Anglo-Saxon there was a word "*cenep*" or "*kenep*"([OE dict](http://old-engli.sh/dictionary.php))([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cenep)) that became "kemp" in Modern English. It meant moustache, and kept that meaning into Middle English, where it also picked up the meaning "rough hair".

[It is said that](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2AckDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT133&lpg=PT133&dq=leofgar%20werede%20his&source=bl&ots=0OdVCvXftj&sig=MD4o6fRgzGboPe80VDScSZ1CnS8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb0KjzgO7VAhWnIMAKHcfCChoQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=leofgar%20werede%20his&f=false) Leofgar, personal priest to Earl Harold Godwinson  "*werede his kenepas on his preosthade*" (wore his moustache during his priesthood, as a sign of his warrior nature)  The Bayeux tapestry attests that the Saxons warriors wore moustaches at this time.

The word "camp", in the sense "effeminate", is a Polari slang derived from *cenep*. It is a bit of ironic slang, the word meaning "hairy, rough, manly" being reversed to mean "smooth, womanly".

As for why it was replaced, that is speculation. A quick glance around shows that while beards with moustache were in fashion in the 16th and 17th century, few men wore only a moustache. Perhaps then the bare chin with hairy upper-lip look seemed very foreign. If there was a Spanish word for this foreign fashion, it could well replace a rarely used, old fashioned English one.